# React Native & React Navigation 5.x: hiding bottom tab bar in specific screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently building an app that has a bottom tab bar with a navigation stack in each tab. Now I want to create an image screen where the tab bar is hidden. I've followed the docs at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens, which works fine if you only want the user to able to navigate to the screen and then navigate back to the tab stack.

The problem is that I want it to feel like the image screen is part of the tab stack so the user can navigate from the image screen to another screen (i.e. push another screen on top of the stack). This doesn't work for me using the method mentioned above...

I've also tried using the option `tabBarVisible: false`, but it makes the "hide animation" glitchy (which the docs also warns for: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator).